# The sum of Fibonacci numbers $F_{4k}$

Tags: summation, fibonacci-numbers

Consider the sum,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n F_{4k}$$
I would like to find this sum,
$F_n$ being the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution:**

Since:

$$
F_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n},
$$

(Please refer to [Fibonacci number - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number))

we have:

$$
F_{4k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4k}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4k}.
$$

Let $a=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4}$ and $b=\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4}$, then:

$$
F_{4k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(a^k-b^k),
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n{F_{4k}}=&\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left( a^k-b^k \right)}\\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[ \left( \sum_{k=0}^n{a^k} \right) -\left( \sum_{k=0}^n{b^k} \right) \right]\\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left( \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}-\frac{1-b^{n+1}}{1-b} \right).
\end{align}
$$

**P.S.**

I wanted to subtitute $a$ and $b$ with their original value, and simplify the formula, but I found the form may be complicated and not simpler than the original result.

(Please refer to [My Attempt based on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify%20%281%2F%285%5E%281%2F2%29%29%29%28%281-a%5E%28n%2B1%29%29%2F%281-a%29-%28%281-b%5E%28n%2B1%29%29%2F%281-b%29%29%29%20with%20a%3D%28%281%2B5%5E%281%2F2%29%29%2F2%29%5E4%2C%20b%3D%28%281-5%5E%281%2F2%29%29%2F2%29%5E4).)

Comment: There _may_ still be a simplification out there. Consider, for instance, that $\sum_{k = 0}^n F_k$ may be calculated exactly the same way (using $a$ and $b$ without fourth powers), and getting the exact same result, but it is also equal to $F_{n+2}-1$. And $\sum_{k = 0}^n F_{2k}$ has a similarly simple closed form. It would be fun if $\sum_{k = 0}^n F_{4k}$ could also have a nicer form. But if it turns out that it doesn't simplify, _proving_ that it doesn't simplify seems daunting.

Comment: I figured out the F(k) one by the fact that F(k)=F((k+1)+1)-F(k+1)  
I figured out the F(2k) one by the fact that F(2k) = F(2(k+1)-1)-F(2k-1)
I figured out the F(3k) one by the fact that F(3k) = (F(3(k+1)-1)/2) - (F(3k-1)/2)
I sadly don't know how to find such a telescoping sum for F(4k)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Prove than
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n F_{4k}=F_{2n}\,F_{2n+2}$$ Induction, may be ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^nF_{4n}=\frac{F_{4n+4}-F_{4n}-3}5$$
It follows by induction because $F_n+F_{n+8}=7F_{n+4}$

Comment: You don't even need induction technically.
Anyway this is the best answer. Thanks

Comment: Also I want to say that I figured out how to do a general sum with f of 2a times k, so thanks for this answer again. F(n-2k)+F(n+2k)= L(2k)F(n)

Comment: I also figured out a formula for 2a+1